# Button not updating the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want to give the users to the ability to update their info on database. I made the button to for the software to take the name from one of the textboxes and send it to the database.

```
public void Updatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Ray-a\\Downloads\\New folder (2)\\Blood Donation\\Blood Donation\\App_Data\\BloodDonationDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True");

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Users set First_Name=@fn WHERE ID = '2' ", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", UFirstName.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}
```

I watched a YouTube video and followed step by step. But it didn't work.
The button works and executes command. But something is wrong with either sql command or connection  because the database doesn't get updated

Comment: You need to do more than watch YouTube videos to learn. You should have read the relevant documentation. Then you'd know that `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of records affected by the operation so you need to look at that number to see whether it worked or not. Either that number is zero and there are no records in the database that match your filter or it's not zero and it worked exactly as it was supposed to.

Comment: By the way, what data type is your ID colum? It looks like its numeric - probably `int`. If so, why do you have quotes around the value? Do you put quotes around your numbers in C# code, or is that just for strings?

Comment: Yeah it's int. Removed quotes  but still have the same problem. So executenonquery is only for retrieving data right? how do you i update instead?

Comment: Are you sure the database you're checking is the one you're updating? A common mistake is creating a Visual Studio project and using a connection string attribute like `AttachDbFileName`, which means your program gets its own independent copy of the database, and the thing you're looking at in SSMS is a completely different copy. Also obligatory: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Just tested it again. Other then the quotes there is nothing wrong with the sql. Managed to get it work by replacing @fn with another value.
So the connection works. it is connected. and the sql works too. The only problem now getting the value from the textbox. And yeah lol. My teacher taught me to use addwithvalue so i am sticking by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  managed to solve the problem.
As it Turns out. clicking the button also calls page_load. Which has a code that replaces text in the textbox. So the button would first call page_load. Retrieving data from the databox. Then it would put in the textbox.

Then it would take data from the same textbox again and send back it to the database.

I managed to fix it by putting the code in pageload inside in if statement. And then i put !Page.IsPostBack condition inside the if statement.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["Active"] != null && Session["Active"].ToString() 
            =="Yes" && !Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                GetUserData();
            }
            
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

because your codes seems okey to me with no problems in it i'll give you some tips that will make sure you almost avoiding most mistakes biggeners like me did which caused unexplaind errors.

these tips will REALLY REALLY help you in your programming journey.

1. when adding a new local database, create a newfolder and name it DataBaseFolder as an example inside your project folder , so you always know where is your database and you dont get confused about other databases in the default location VS saves them, and its better that the project folder is placed in the partition "C" in a default folder of windows.
2. when creating a new table, name it probably in the definition part at the bottom where you can see:
   `create table [dbo].[TableName]` then press Ctrl + s, make sure to save that table in the same folder as your database, so you always know this table is for this project.
3. )))) each time you update your table definition like column name or type, or adding a new column or deleting an existing one, make sure to press Ctrl +s and save the table (replace) in the same folder you originally created it, that will make sure you don't get the error most new developers like me were stuck at which is the update window is taking forever to preview the changes.
4. ))))) to make it easy for myself to use the sql commands, i created a script (class.cs) and put the important codes in methods with parameters so i save a lot of time when i was restarting over my program because of some mistakes i did :D

first i defined my sql connection in the class named SqlCodes:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Ray-a\\Downloads\\New folder (2)\\Blood Donation\\Blood Donation\\App_Data\\BloodDonationDB.mdf\";Integrated Security=True");
```

then i created my methods, examples:

```
public void QueryCommand(string QueryString) 
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}

public void FillingDataGridView(parameter1,parameter2, parameter3) 
    {
    con.Open();
   some code;
    con.Close();
    }
```

So, back to my main class where my button will function:

```
SqlCodes sqlCodes = new SqlCodes();
```

in the button i now can write:

```
sqlCodes.QueryCommand("insert into MyTable values (your values)");
```

or

```
sqlCodes.RefreshDataGridViewAfterEntry (parameter1,parameter2,parameter3)
```

or

```
string queryCommand = " insert into MyTable values (your values)";
sqlCodes.QueryCommand(queryCommand);
```

or in the load form method so when you open the program it shows the data you want instantly

```
{
sqlCodes.FillingDataGridview(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3)
}
```

5. if you're having errors with your database, don't delete the files you will find in the solution explorer because it will cause you some errors i couldn't figure their solution, just delete the database in the server explorer, and don't forget to change the sql connection path in the SqlCodes Class you created.

that will save you time and and to avoid errors and make your code very simple, instead of copy paste/ writing about 7 or 8 lines each time you want to do something with your database.